# how to record video of selenium tests running on Xvfb?

Tags: python, selenium, ffmpeg, xvfb

I want a video recording of my selenium tests (chromedriver running on linux server with Xvfb).

How would you go about doing this with ffmpeg or does a library already exist? I also would like the output to be a choppy gif (I just need to know the basics of what is happening).

Comment: this question could be posted here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this : https://github.com/lightsofapollo/x-recorder

What it does is pretty simple : start an xvfb-run of your command, then record the X11 output with ffmpeg.

Comment: That package does not work with new node for at least 4 years

https://github.com/lightsofapollo/x-recorder/issues/3

Comment: So get on it ;)