# Record selenium tests in headless mode (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, record, headless

I need to record selenium tests in *chrome* using **headless** mode but I have been finding it impossible.

To sum up, the application that I am working with is a Java application with its frontend and backend that the main function is to do selenium testing. Even though it has a lot more features. I only want to record the tests from when they start until they finish.

So far I have tried recording with the library WebDriverManager following [this](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#recordings) example but it did not work probably because it only works with a headful navigator.

I have seen the following [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192198/how-to-video-record-selenium-tests-running-headless-inside-a-docker) that uses the library **ffmpeg** but it says that it works in docker and I need to use it in windows/linux and as I said before, my application it is not just a test, it also has a UI with different features.

Do you know about more possibilities to video-record my selenium tests in headless mode?

Comment: headless mode has no GUI to record.  It's probably enough to just output a report detailing which actions have passed/failed along with any exceptions received.

Answer (score 0):

If you use headless mode only because you don't have a video device in Linux, then you can try [Xvfb](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2018/07/21/running-headful-chrome-on-ubuntu-server.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).