Record video of test execution in selenium python pytest
I have this code written in my conftest to record video of test execution, this works fine in a machine with a screen for e.g a PC. But as soon as it is run through Jenkins in a pipeline on a VM it doesn't record anything. Please let me know if there is a way to record execution on a VM?
def start_video_recording():
        os.makedirs(video_folder, exist_ok=True)
        screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
        print("Screen resolution size: {}x{}".format(screen_width, screen_height))
        print("Video Recording Started")
        global video_recording
        resolution = (1920, 1080)
        codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
        fps = 60.0
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S")
        filename_video = os.path.join(video_folder, f"video_{timestamp}.MP4")
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename_video, codec, fps, resolution)
        while video_recording:
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
        out.release()
        if filename_video is not None:
                    allure.attach.file(filename_video, name="Test_Video", attachment_type=AttachmentType.MP4)
                    print(f"Video attached: {filename_video}")
    
    def stop_video_recording():
        global video_recording
        video_recording = False
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print("Video Recording Stopped.")


You can install a virtual display like xvfb so that you can run record the screen. Might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51265680/8784827

This is a module for unix what about running in windows @Payrfix
